# iOS (iPhone, iPad) development RSS list? here are my 35 RSS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

Here is my favorite iOS (iPhone) development RSS list. Around 35 sites.

Daily, I get many useful information from the following great RSS and I'd like to share them with you.

Please let us know your RSS list ~

iPhoneDev
http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/feed/

71²
http://feeds.feedburner.com/71squared

Able Pear Software
http://blog.ablepear.com/feeds/posts/default

Blog : Mobisoft Infotech
http://feeds.feedburner.com/BlogMobisoftInfotech

blog.sallarp.com
http://blog.sallarp.com/feed/

Cocoa Dev Blog
http://feeds.feedburner.com/CocoaDevBlog

Cocoa Is My Girlfriend
http://feeds.feedburner.com/CocoaIsMyGirlfriend

Cocoa Samurai
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

Cocoa with Love
http://feeds.feedburner.com/CocoaWithLove

cocos2d for iPhone
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/feed/rss

Cult of Mac
http://feeds.feedburner.com/cultofmac/bFow

Dr. Touch
http://www.drobnik.com/touch/feed/

Enormego Developer Blog
http://feeds2.feedburner.com/EnormegoDevelopers

How to Make iPhone Apps
http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/feed/

iCodeBlog
http://feeds.feedburner.com/icodeblog

iPhone Developer Tips
http://feeds2.feedburner.com/IphoneDeveloperTips

iPhone Development
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

iPhone iOS 4 iTV iPad SDK Development Tutorials, Programming Tips, News
http://feeds.feedburner.com/maniacdev

iPhone OS Development Blog
http://feeds.feedburner.com/IphoneDevelopment

iPhone SDK Articles
http://feeds.feedburner.com/iPhoneSDKArticles

iPhone SDK Tutorial for Beginners
http://adeem.me/blog/feed

iPhoneDevelopmentBits
http://iphonedevelopmentbits.com/feed/rss/

iPhoneFlow
http://feeds.feedburner.com/iPhoneFlow

John Wang
http://feeds.feedburner.com/JohnTWang

markjnet
http://www.markj.net/feed/

Matt Legend Gemmell
http://mattgemmell.com/feed/rss

MK Blog
http://feeds.feedburner.com/MugunthKumar

Mobile Orchard
http://feeds2.feedburner.com/MobileOrchard

NotTooBad Blogging
http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/feed/

Ole Begemann: iOS Development
http://feeds.feedburner.com/ole-begemann-dev-blog

programmer-on-the-street 
http://al-lea.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

Ray Wenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/feed

Steve @ DynamicEdge
http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/feed/

The Flying Jalapeno Lives
http://feeds2.feedburner.com/TheFlyingJalapenoLives

Trails in the Sand
http://feeds.feedburner.com/TrailsInTheSand

vorm + beweging
http://feeds.feedburner.com/vormplusbeweging

Comment: You should make this a community wiki

Comment: @Flash84x :) Ok, I'll make it.

Comment: can you provide us with opml for this ^.^

Comment: How did this non-question get three upvotes? I suggest *possibly* migrating this so Apple.SE